# L a finite distributive lattice, prove subsposet of L that cover k elements is isomorphic to the subposet of L that are covered by k elements.

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let L be a finite distributive lattice. Then I need to prove that the subposet of elements that cover k elements is isomorphic to the subposet of elements that are covered by k elements.

I know the fundamental theorem of finite distributive lattices tells us that L is isomorphic to the poset of order ideals on the join-irreducible elements of L, but I'm not sure how to use that here. The problem appears as number 38 in chapter 3 of Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics 1, and the solution in the book gives the bijection and says that using FTFDL makes it easy to see why the bijection works, but I really don't have any clue why. The bijection Stanley gives is

phi(t)=sup(u : u not greater than or equal to any x in the join irreducible representation of t)

No clue what's going on here, could anyone help me understand this bijection?

Comment: Either I don't actually understand what you're asking, or the result is false. It seems to me that you're asking to prove that the poset of elements covering $k$ elements is isomorphic to the poset of elements covered by $k$ elements in the lattice. Now let $P$ be the poset which is a five elements [fence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fence_(mathematics)), with three elements below and two above, like so: $$a<u>b>v>c,$$ and let $L$ be the lattice of order-ideals of $P$ (this is like a cube with three extra squares "on top of it").

Comment: For $k=2$, both posets of elements covering and being covered by $2$ elements have six elements, but they're not isomorphic (they both have three minimal elements and a top one, but in one of them all three minimal elements are below all not minimal elements, and in the other this doesn't happen). Or else I got it wrong. Can you confirm this example?

Answer (score 1):

Thes result is false. It is confirmed in the Errata for Stanley's book on his website. Apologies.